# Finding Odd Parity While Summing Number

Tags: java

So I'm trying to take a given number, and add up all the digits. Then after finding the sum, determine if the sum is even or odd. Here's what I have so far

```
public static boolean oddParity(int inputnumber) {
    int sum = 0;
    while (inputnumber > 0) {
        sum = sum + inputnumber % 10;
        inputnumber = inputnumber / 10;
    }
    return sum;
    if ((sum % 2) == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    oddParity(1234);
}
```

Right now I get an error at the "return sum;" line saying it can't convert from an int to a boolean. I'm at a loss as to what to fix here, and I feel like it's going to be something small I messed up. Any help?

Comment: remove `return sum;` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You error is coming since you are returning a int value at  return sum; from a method having boolean as return type.

So remove

```
return sum;
```

Comment: Did that and the error is gone. But now it doesn't even run. I'm not sure if it's an issue with the method or with Eclipse, but I hit run to test it and nothing comes up. No console, nothing.

Comment: You are only displaying code for method oddParity() only. So its difficult to say why its not running. Share your complete code. Meanwhile your actual problem is solved so please accept my answer

Comment: Here's my main: 
'public static void main(String[] args) {
     oddParity(1234);
}'

Comment: It runs properly. Since you are not printing anything nothing comes on console. do you want to print true or false value returned from oddParity method ?? if yes do System.out.println(oddParity(1234)); in main method

Comment: I am an idiot, I should've know that. Thank you so much for all your help!